# Python remove characters until letter or number

Tags: python, regex, string

I am working on a script that reads a file that contains a linux tree output, and I would like to remove the tree formatting at the beginning of each line.  However I would like to keep the spacing that is in the string after the first letter or number.

This is what I have so far:

```
import re
with open(tree_loc) as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'batman' in line:
            line = re.sub(r'[^\w*]', '', line)
            print(line)
```

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'^\W+', '', line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a non regular-expression solution?

```
>>> from string import letters, digits
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> 
>>> keep = set(letters + digits)
>>> s = '$@@^test123'
>>> ''.join(dropwhile(lambda c: c not in keep, s))
'test123'
```